# Mac OS X file/folder watch that updates on multiple computers

Tags: macos, adobe-premiere

Here is the scenario: We're using the CS5 Master Suite.

At work, another editor and I are using iMac's to edit video projects - I know. (they're the late 2009 dual core models)

We have a drobo to save all the files to. We're connected to it on a gigabit connection, but only connected to the network at 100 Mbit.

We need a system in which we have folders locally on our computers that we bring down from the Drobo to work on, and that are synced on the server so that the other editor can use the project files at the same time, and to make sure the most up to date version is on there.

Need a system where we can check in and out projects. Much like how Dreamweaver works.

Is there a software out there to accomplish this?? It doesn't have to be anything complicated, just need a good folder sync, and check in/out solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a version control software such as cvs, svn or git, git probably being the fastest and easiest. These are command line tools hat do all of the above operations (check in/ out, lock, synchronize work, etc). These are typically used for software projects but can be used for any type of project. If you are not command line saavy there are a ton of options for graphical client interfaces so that you can have a GUI instead of using a shell. In fact git-gui is bundled with git. The primary issue here is that a NAS like drobo has a limited operating system and you can not just install software like an svn server on it. So you will have to run the version control software on a separate machine and map the drobo as a shared drive as the actual storage